# Vector key gets lost when searching through it

Tags: c++, vector

I have an vector array in my class which is made to hold pointers to a specific object pointers.

The class should contain methods allowing for adding, removing and finding the objects inside.
The class right now looks like this:

```
class VectorKontener: public Kontener <VectorKontener> {
protected:
    int find(Obiekt &n) {
        cout << endl << "---------------------" << endl << "Running find method loop!" << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < stos.size(); i++) {
            cout << "Now running for id: " << stos[i]->getId() << endl;
            if (stos[i] == &n) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
public:
    VectorKontener::VectorKontener(Obiekt &n) {
        add(n);
    }

    VectorKontener add(Obiekt &n) {
        cout << "Adding: " << n.getId() << endl;

        stos.push_back(&n);

        return *this;
    }

    int checkPresent(Obiekt &n) {
        return this->find(n) != -1;
    }

    VectorKontener remove(Obiekt &n) {
        if (this->checkPresent(n)) {
            stos.erase(stos.begin() + this->find(n));
        }
        else
            cout << endl <<"ELEMENT NOT IN CONTAINER" << endl;

        return *this;
    }

    VectorKontener display() {
        cout << endl << "===DISPLAY===" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < stos.size(); i++) {
            stos[i]->display();
        }

        return *this;
    }
};
```

However when running for test data of:

```
void Zad3()
{
    Obiekt 
        obj1(5), 
        obj2(23), 
        obj3(234), 
        obj4(33);


    cout << endl << "1. Class init" << endl;
    VectorKontener k1(obj1);

    cout << endl << "2. Adding other objects into array" << endl;

    k1
        .add(obj2)
        .add(obj3)
        .display();

    cout << endl << "3. Element remove attempt" << endl;
    k1
        .remove(obj2)
        .display();

    getchar();
}
```

The output looks like so:

```
1. Class init
Adding: 5

2. Adding other objects into array
Adding: 23
Adding: 234

===DISPLAY===
This object has id: 5
This object has id: 23
This object has id: 234

3. Element remove attempt

---------------------
Running find method loop!
Now running for id: 5
Now running for id: 23

---------------------
Running find method loop!
Now running for id: 5
Now running for id: 23

===DISPLAY===
This object has id: 5
```

The output makes it seem like the third variable of the array becomes lost in the *find* method (hehe) since it is not calculated by it, despite `stos.size()` showing the proper value (2).

I am not a cpp expert, to be fair pretty far from it, and am aware this might be a pretty noobish issue, but I have really ran out of ways to make it work properly.

Any help would be really amazing

Comment: Why are your methods returning copies? Seems rather wasteful - also it means that `k1` is not modified on the second chained `add` call

Comment: @UnholySheep I'm used to work with method chaining, and thought it would work ok here

Comment: It would work if your methods returned *references*, not copies - change the return value to `VectorKontener&` (instead of `VectorKontener`)

Comment: @UnholySheep Worked...i'm a moron. Thank you. Could you post as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the functions return *copies* of the object, meaning that in the chained `add` call the original object is not modified (on the second and any subsequent function call), instead a temporary one is created on each function call that gets destroyed right after.

The simple fix is to change the return value to a *reference*, e.g.: for the add function:

```
VectorKontener& add(Obiekt &n) {
```

instead of

```
VectorKontener add(Obiekt &n) {
```

And similar changes for the other functions.